# Selenium except NoSuchElementException not working in my python script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a very simple code where I am looking for a class and when that class doesn't exist I want to catch that and update a status in my CSV. I am implementing  this like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

invalid = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_3lLzD')
try:
    Update status
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    Update Status
```

It still throws me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Krenovate/Desktop/automate/automate/automate.py", line 35, in <module>
    invalid = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_3lLzD')
  File "C:\Users\Krenovate\PycharmProjects\mxrecord\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Krenovate\PycharmProjects\mxrecord\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Krenovate\PycharmProjects\mxrecord\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Krenovate\PycharmProjects\mxrecord\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ._3lLzD
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), the locator function is designed to throw an exception if it is not found. Therefore, the exception that you get is well within the expected behavior.

If you are unsure of the presence of the element, the easiest way is to place it within a try block

```
try:
    invalid = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_3lLzD')
    Update status
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    Update Status
```

or use [explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) with a timeout.